# What is the quickest way to remove all staged files in git?

Tags: git

Within Git Bash, I'm attempting to merge *branchTheirs* into *branchMine*. When I run `git merge branchTheirs`, I have merge conflicts that need to be resolved. These merge conflicts are shown underneath the section "Unmerged paths:" in the CLI.

```
Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
        both modified:   src/main/java/gov/hrsa/nextgen/sitepoc/api/config/CachingConfiguration.java
        both modified:   src/main/java/gov/hrsa/nextgen/sitepoc/api/constants/ApiDocumentationConstants.java
```

Okay, that's what I expect.

However, underneath the CLI's section "Changes to be committed:", (the staging area?) there is a long list of files, some modified and some new, which I do not want to push with de-conflicted files.

```
Changes to be committed:
        modified:   ../career-portal-api/pom.xml
        modified:   ../career-portal-api/src/main/java/gov/hrsa/nextgen/cp/api/CareerPortalApiApplication.java
        modified:   ../career-portal-api/src/test/resources/test.properties
[very long list of files in numerous drectories]
```

How can I remove all staged files before committing my de-conflicted files?

Comment: Have a look at the new “restore” command and the “—staged” option.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I remove all staged files before committing my de-conflicted files?

First, the right answer is probably: **don't do it.**  (Unless you're doing something very advanced.)

Second, if you *do* want to do it, you can use `git reset` on each such file, either one at a time, or all in one command such as:

```
git reset -- file1 file2 ... fileN
```

Remember that the effect of changing the index copy of the files back to match the `HEAD` copy of the files means that the next commit will *not use* all the stuff brought in from the other commit—i.e., throw out *all* of the changes the other guy did on his other branch, keeping all files the same as they are in your branch.

This kind of reset is similar to `git checkout HEAD -- file1 file2 ... fileN`, except that the `git checkout` variant not only copies the `HEAD` copy to the index, but also then copies the index copy (which is now the same as the `HEAD` copy) to the work-tree so that you can see what you're about to commit.  That would lose the merge work entirely, which almost certainly not something you want.  So `git reset` is likely more sensible than `git checkout` here, but neither one seems all that likely to be what you want.

Still, if it *is* what you want, you can get a more convenient-to-use list of file names using `git status --short` or `git status --porcelain`.  For instance:

```
git status --short > /tmp/instructions
[edit /tmp/instructions; replace first three columns of each line with `git reset --`]
sh /tmp/instructions      # run each `git reset`
```

Leaving the work-tree copy alone, via `git reset` instead of `git checkout`, means that `git status` will now compare the index and work-tree, and show a lot of `changes not staged for commit`.  If you use `git status --short`, those show up as a letter in the second column—the first column letters show you differences between `HEAD` and index.

(Resetting or checking out like this tends to be one of two ways that programmers throw out someone else's work during a merge, usually without intending to do that.  Hence the "don't" advice.  Using:

```
git reset -- .
```

—a slight variant of [Gomes's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58665402/1256452)—means *copy all the files from `HEAD` to the index, recursively, from the current directory downward.*  Done from the top level, this not only resets away the changes you brought in via merge, but also resets the conflicted entries.  That is probably not what you want either.)

Answer (score 1):

```
git reset HEAD -- .
```

This would probably do the trick. `git reset head` is the command used to unstage a file, and `.` resets everything in the current directory.

Be careful. As mentioned by torek, the command `git reset HEAD` will erase the record of the ongoing merge. However, if that command is used with a filename such as `git reset HEAD myfile.txt`, it will simply unstage the file, meaning if you commit, then that file won't be included in your commit.

Comment: But this will also cancel the merge, will it not?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. All "git reset head [filename]" does is unstage changes that you currently have staged. It should not change the status of your merge. After you use git reset on the files you don't want to be part of your merge commit(i.e. git reset HEAD [filename]), you can add back the files you want to be in the merge by using git add [filename]). And after all the files you want in the merge are staged, you can commit the changes. Here is a link about git reset that might be helpful https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/resetting-checking-out-and-reverting

Comment: `git reset HEAD` will in fact erase the record of the ongoing merge. However, `git reset HEAD -- .` will not. `git reset HEAD *` is more like `git reset HEAD -- .`, except that the shell expands `*` (except on Windows) and if a file is named `--hard` that could be bad. :-)

Comment: Thank you torek, I guess those points would have been good to mention in my original answer